# Função assíncrona com FutureBuilder retorando uma lista de Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

Minha função obtinha dados de um sistema e montava os `widgets`. Ela era síncrona e funciona perfeitamente.

```
  children: _confere
      .obterDados(data)
      .map(
        (d) => Conferencia(
          dados: d,
        ),
      )
      .toList()
```

Agora surgiu a necessidade de torná-la assíncrona. Aí surgiu a dor de cabeça com `FutureBuilder`.

Tentei de várias formas iterar sobre o resultado e retornar uma lista de `wigets`, mas sem sucesso.

O mais próximo que consegui foi com o código abaixo:

```
children: <Widget>[
FutureBuilder(
  future: _confere.obterDados(data),
  builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<ObservableList<Dados>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Conferencia(dados: snapshot.data[2]);
    } else {
      return (Text('consultando'));
    }
  },
  ),
],
```

Obviamente, neste código só é retornado um único resultado. Gostaria de saber como retornar o resultado da iteração utilizando `FutureBuilder`. A maioria dos exemplos que vi só retornam `widget` único e nunca, uma lista.

Comment: Se seu `snapshot.data` é uma lista e vc espera também uma lista, vc poderia criar uma variável nova dentro da função do builder e com um laço de repetição percorrer o snapshot e populando a variável. Depois poderia retornar dentro do seu widget essa lista. Pensou em algo do tipo?

Comment: @LeonardoPaim tentei, mas quanto tento retornar uma lista mostra o err: _The return type 'List<Widget>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.` acredito que devido `<Widget>[_

Se removo o `<Widget>` e deixo retorno como `List<Widget>`
_The argument type 'FutureBuilder<ObservableList<Dados>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>_

Comment: @LeonardoPaim encontrei uma solução com base na sua informação, porém criando uma novo função `Future<List<Widget>> _widgets() async {`, vou aguardar caso queira postar uma resposta, senão eu coloco a solução que encontrei.

Comment: Sem problemas, poste a solução que funcionou pra você. Inicialmente a minha sugestão era algo genérico para que pudesse direcionar a vc na resposta específica do seu problema. Como o Stack preza pelas respostas efetivas para problemas específicos, o melhor é que vc deixe para a comunidade a solução que vc aplicou e solucionou o problema que inicialmente vc estava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vi que você já encontrou uma solução, mas só pra deixar mais uma possibilidade de como pode ser feito:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _conferencia.obterDados(data),
  builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<ObservableList<Dados>> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData)
      return Center(child: Text("Carregando dados!"));

    return SeuWidget(
      children: snapshot.data.map((item){
        return Conferencia(dados: item);
      }).toList()
    );

  },
),
```

**Explicação**

O `FutureBuilder` tem a função de aguardar os dados de alguma fonte e depois quando possuir os dados ele irá re-construir, mas enquanto os dados não chegam você pode informar ao usuário que algo está acontecendo, então é por isso que faço a seguinte validação

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return Center(child: Text("Carregando dados!"));
```

Então enquanto os dados não chegarem, informamos o usuário que estamos esperando ou carregando as informações!

Comment: Exatamente isso! 
Mas esse `return Container();` tem alguma função?

Comment: O future vai construir apenas quando tiver dados... Então enquanto não tiver nenhum dado ele vai construir um espaço em branco, ou melhor tu pode por o teu `Text("Carregando...")` para informar que está esperando algum dados. Ajustei a resposta, de uma olhadinha!

Comment: Está faltando o else no `if (!snapshot.hasData) {` ou não está fechando a `{` para retornar `return SeuWidget(`

Comment: Oops! Falha minha, não vi a chave aberta ali, só remover ela. ~~ Não cheguei a testar, estou sem Flutter na máquina.